# What are the cases in which Facebook Messenger Platform sends multiple events to a Webhook within one request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

On [Facebook Messenger Developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#format), it is mentioned that:

> Note that entry is an array and may contain multiple objects, so ensure your code iterates over it to process all events. For a complete description of event properties, see Webhooks Reference.

I've checked out most of the docs on various webhook events (e.g. [messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messages) etc), but they all seem to only have one object in the entry array.

In what cases does an entry array have multiple objects?

Comment: For example when two events occur “simultaneously”, Facebook might just send one request.

Comment: Hm would you be able to provide a concrete example with the contents of the POST request from FB to the Webhook? Or point me to the page in FB's docs on it. Thanks!

Comment: Documentation is right in the place where you already linked to. `entry` is simply an array of objects - so what you see there, `{ "id": ... "time": ... "messaging": ... }` will simply be repeated multiple times in such a case. Simply write your code so that it _loops_ over whatever `entry` may contain - then it won’t really matter whether you get one, two or a dozen entries.

Comment: @LeeHe did you find it out? I wish to know too.. Specially if it can send an event with entries for distinct pages.